# How to easily view all modules loaded by application (war file)?

Tags: java, jboss7.x, classloader

I'm having a hard time figuring out which explicit/implicit modules have been loaded by my application. And this is a must have information in order to solve the classloading problems that I'm having. It seems that the docs are not up to date on which implicit modules are loaded by default (this has been changing in the latest versions).

So does anyone know how to list all modules that an application ends up loading? I tried setting the TRACE level for the "org.jboss.modules" logger but it's too verbose and didn't help much.

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.0.1 (7.1.3).